# How to generate a hex without main function using IAR linker - xlink?

Tags: linker, embedded, workbench, iar, xlink

The point is to generate a hex without main function using IAR linker - xlink?
This code should be loaded into the RAM of RL78 MCU.

Comment: What do you have working so far? I assume you've got a library project generating something like `library.a`?

Comment: Looks like an XY question; what are you actually trying to achieve? Dynamic loading/linking perhaps? A fully linked application must have an entry-point.  The GNU linker supports an option known as "partial linking", not sure about yours.

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search of `iar generate hex from library` brought me to [this document, "Creating an Absolutely Placed Library"](https://www.iar.com/contentassets/e2f634ff2543432ca78f582f05ed3fe4/creating-an-absolutely-placed-library-pdf-2.pdf), as a first result. It has all the information you need, plus some information on using a CRC for consistency checking. The document is for the IAR EWRX variant, but the concepts should all be the same.

The basic process is to compile your library as an executable, but without a `main()` function in it. You'll need to set your library configuration under General -> Library Options to `None`. You can also setup your file conversion settings at this point.

Since you don't have a `main()` function for a program entry point, you will need to create an entry function to call the IAR C runtime initialization function, `__iar_data_init2()`, and then set the linker to use this function as the entry point (which can be found under Linker Options -> Library Options).

When building a library, all the symbols will be preserved until the final link step for the application using it, but since you are building this as an executable, it is important that the symbols you want to keep have the `__root` keyword, or under Linker -> Extra Options you can specify `--no-remove` to keep all symbols.

In the next step, you need to use `isymexport` to export the symbols that you want. You will need a file to direct the tool what to export. In the example, they have a file that just contains the following:

```
show lib_*
show __checksum*
```

This will direct the tool to export all symbols beginning with `lib_` and all symbols beginning with `__checksum`. They note that `__iar_data_init2()` should **not** be exported, as this would cause conflicts with the application that ultimately will use this code. You invoke the tool like so:

```
isymexport <path to .out file> <path to output from tool> --edit <path to file created above>
```

Now you should have the output from `isymexport` and the library file that you were looking for. For the application using this library, you'll need to add the output from `isymexport` as a library under Linker -> Library, and in your application, you'll need to call your entry function in the library before you attempt to use any of the library's symbols.

This should be the information you need to generate a library that lives in a hex file and can be loaded separately, as well as how to use that library. The referenced document has a lot more detail, so if it is available at that link (or can be found elsewhere by title) it will be a better reference than my summary here.

Comment: Although a link to documentation is useful, you should also actually *answer* the question on SO so that it stands alone (should the link become broken for example).  Surrounding the link with superfluous comment on how you found it, and unrelated suggestions does not save it from being a link-only answer.

Comment: I will add a summary to the answer.